# rake task with assignment ||= coming back nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

Why in my rake task is the hash still returning nil?

```
namespace :pull_and_update_liverail_daily do
  desc 'Pull and Update'
  task :by_date,  [:date_start, :date_end] => :environment do |t,args|
    args[:date_start] ||= DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    args[:date_end]   ||= DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    Rake::Task["stats:import_all"].invoke(args[:date_start], args[:date_end])
    Rake::Task["update_daily_stats:by_date"].invoke(args[:date_start])
  end
end
```

This works though..

```
    date_start = args[:date_start] || DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_end   = args[:date_end]   || DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`with_defaults`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Rake/TaskArguments/with_defaults):

```
namespace :pull_and_update_liverail_daily do
  desc 'Pull and Update'
  task :by_date,  [:date_start, :date_end] => :environment do |t,args|
    args.with_defaults(date_start: DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                       date_end: DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    Rake::Task["stats:import_all"].invoke(args[:date_start], args[:date_end])
    Rake::Task["update_daily_stats:by_date"].invoke(args[:date_start])
  end
end
```

---

When you try to do this:

```
args[:date_start] = DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

what actually happens is:

```
args.[]=(:date_start, DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

(it calls the method `[]=`)

Since `TaskArguments` does not define a `[]=` method its [`method_missing`](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb#L64) is called, which tries to find the value of an argument named `:[]=`:

> ```
> def method_missing(sym, *args)
>   lookup(sym.to_sym)
> end
> ```

which explains why values are not changed, but you don't get any exception...

Comment: The reason for this is because that params hash holds an empty string and ||= works if the left is nil right?

Comment: The reason is because `args` is not a `hash`, but a `TaskArguments` instance. If the value was an empty string, the second approach the OP suggests would have not worked either.

Answer (score -1):

That's the same as

```
nil ||= DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

You can't assign anything to a instance of NilClass. That's why your second option works.

```
date_start = args[:date_start] || DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Here you are have a variable to create, and if args[:date_start] is nil continues taking yesterday date.

Comment: This will result in error (`Can't assign to nil`) - which was not what the OP describes...

Comment: The `||=` operator can also be used to assign values on hashes. Your assumptions are off and thus this whole answer is wrong. The real issue here is that `args` is not a hash.

Comment: I have - the values stay nil, no exception was reported - `rake task with assignment ||= coming back nil` your code throws an exception - it does not explains what happens to the OP. If you are curious, you can read my answer to see what actually happened.